# iPhone plist data, large amounts of text and return key?

Tags: ios, iphone, command, plist

I've built my app using a plist. But with the data there is a few times when I need to press return and start a new line. The return key doesn't work in the plist. If I did it the older way it would be \n\n but that doesn't work either.

Is there a obvious way I'm overlooking? Or will it be a case off just pressing the space bar a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is not a case of just pressing the space bar a lot. If you want to insert a return in a plist in Xcode or Plist-Editor, you can use option-return.